# Not able to start hwi in hive 2.0.0

Tags: hive

I have my hive-hwi-2.0.0.war file in lib folder, right where it should be.

In my `hive-site.xml`, I have these overridden the configurations :

```
<property>
    <name>hive.hwi.listen.host</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
   </property>
   <property>
    <name>hive.hwi.listen.port</name>
    <value>9998</value>
   </property>
   <property>
    <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
    <value>/lib/hive-hwi-2.0.0.war</value>
    <description>This sets the path to the HWI war file, relative to ${HIVE_HOME}. </description>
   </property>
```

But it just does not find it.

When I run the command ,`hive --service hwi`,It throws an error,

HI war file not found at .... location.

What could really be the issue here?

Comment: could you check if the war file does really exist? by doing `$ls /lib/hive-hwi-2.0.0.war` for example?

Comment: @user1314742: There is hive-hwi-2.0.0.jar. I believe that should work?